# Show Bing map in website

Tags: php, html, bing-maps

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx) of adding bing map

and from that link it can show map in bing website.

http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?sp=adr.1%20Microsoft%20Way%2C%20Redmond%2C%20WA%2098052

have tried using it in image but it displays nothing .
used it as    al ink

```
<a href="http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?sp=adr.1%20Microsoft%20Way%2C%20Redmond%2C%20WA%2098052" >show</a>
```

How can i show it in my website  ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use iframes:

```
<iframe
    width="100%"
    height="500"
    frameborder="0" 
    src="http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?sp=adr.1%20Microsoft%20Way%2C%20Redmond%2C%20WA%2098052">
</iframe>
```